# android showing text within a image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

In project I need to show first text within the image (Q letter image) and second text below the Q letter as show in the picture.  How can I place the text as shown in the image?

[image]

The Q icon image can be shown on map as like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a TextView and set its background property to your image.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/q_text
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/q_placeholder_text"
    android:background="@drawable/q_drawable" />
```

Or even better, add both the ImageView and the TextView to a FrameLayout.  (The TextView and ImageView order matters)

```
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/q_layout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/q_image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:src="@drawable/q_drawable />
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/q_text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:text="@string/q_placeholder_text />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this:
1. Create a Linear layout which have white background.
2. Use LinearLayout in side above layout and set q image as back ground. this q image is png image.
2. Use Textview in side linear layout and set text what you want with new line.

I hope, it will work.

Comment: please explain me "q image" mean q image without the white background and explain your second point.

Comment: q image is png image and set white background parent or base layout.